# pythonic way to update dict with sum of function

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have different dictionaries where the keys are pandas timestamp and values are function taking all one input argument.

```
In [172]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [173]: import pandas as pd

In [174]: def f(x):
     ...:     pass
     ...: def g(x):
     ...:     pass
     ...: def h(x):
     ...:     pass
     ...: 

In [175]: dictionary = OrderedDict(zip(keys, [f, g, h]))

In [176]: def l(x):
     ...:     pass
     ...: 

In [177]: dictionary2 = OrderedDict(zip(pd.date_range('20190101', '20200101', freq='BA'), [l]))
```

Now I would like to update `dictionary` with `dictionary2` and if they are sharing keys the updated dictionary should hold a function which is the sum of the others. If I do a simple update it just overrides it:

```
In [178]: dictionary.update(zip(dictionary2.keys(), dictionary2.values()))

In [179]: dictionary
Out[179]: 
OrderedDict([(Timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00', freq='BA-DEC'),
              <function __main__.f>),
             (Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00', freq='BA-DEC'),
              <function __main__.l>),
             (Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00', freq='BA-DEC'),
              <function __main__.h>)])
```

However what I would like to have is that we get a new function (name doesnt matter) which is the sum of `g` and `l` in this case. There are two question:

1. Is there another way of defining a sum of function than:

   ```
   In [180]: def H(f, g):
        ...:     def _h(x):
        ...:         return f(x) + g(x)
        ...:     return _h
        ...: 

   In [181]:
   ```
2. How do I update then a dict in a pythonic way.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done unpythonically?

Comment: Are you aware that `dictionary.update(zip(dictionary2.keys(), dictionary2.values()))` is total overkill? `dictionary.update(dictionary2)` works fine.

Comment: Are you facing a situation where `dictionary2` is actually a dict, or you are constructing it thinking the merge will be easier that way?

Comment: @MadPhysicist they are both dictionaries.

Comment: It is also totally irrelevant that you are using pandas. Your example will be more minimal and general if you make the keys just letters or something.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree, it was just convenient for me since I'm using timestamps in reality as well

Comment: Keep in mind that this site is to benefit others with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to process the keys that overlap using a dict comprehension, then update `dictionary` with `dictionary2` followed by the overlaps.

To find the sums:

```
sums = {k: lambda x, f1=dictionary[k], f2=dictionary2[k]: f1(x) + f2(x) for k in dictionary2 if k in dictionary}
```

A lambda should be fine since you explicitly state that the name of the function is irrelevant. I cheat a little and extract the dictionary values up front using the default parameters to the lambda, whose values are bound immediately in each iteration  of the comprehension. If I had done `dictionary[k](x) + dictionary2[k](x)` in the lambda, the functions would only be bound when the lambda is called, by which point the value from `dictionary` would have been  lost.

Your way of doing the sum is arguably more Pythonic than what I propose here with a lambda with two additional parameters:

```
def s(f, g):
    def h(x): return f(x) + g(x)
    return h
sums = {k: s(dictionary[k], dictionary2[k]) for k in dictionary2 if k in dictionary}
```

To update:

```
dictionary.update(dictionary2)
dictionary.update(sums)
```